# Get computer name using serial number of server remotely

Tags: batch-file

Can anybody tell me how get to know the computer name using serial number remotely?

Like using

```
wmic bios get computername where serialnumber="XXXXXX"
```

I need to know computer names of using multiple serial numbers.

Comment: Does http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/finding-machines-with-from-list-of-serial-numbers/ help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use net use to get a list of computers. Then ask each one what is it's serial number.

```
For /f "tokens=1* delims=\ " %A in ('net view^|findstr /c:"\\"') do echo %A>> computerlist.txt
wmic /node:@computerlist.txt bios get SerialNumber /format:csv|findstr /i /c:"ENTER SERIAL NUM HERE"
```

or to get all in a nice file

```
wmic /node:@computerlist.txt bios get SerialNumber /format:htable>ServerSerialNumbers.htm
start "" ServerSerialNumbers.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Batch** You can do this like below:

```
wmic /node:[remote computer name] bios get computername where serialnumber="XXXXXX"
```

Or, if you would like to output to a text file:

```
set myfile = [The full UNC path with filename e.g. \\server\share\filename.txt]

wmic /append:%myfile% /node:[remote computer name] bios get computername where serialnumber="XXXXXX"
```

**In Powershell** Do like this, Just open the shell with Admin rights, and type::

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName [remote computer name]-Class Win32_BIOS -Filter 'SerialNumber="XXXXXX"' | Select -Property PSComputerName
```

Comment: Here we need the remote computer name. Only I know the serialnumber. In your command, I need to put computer details too, which i dont know.