# Remotely get serial number and model from list file and export it to arranged excel

Tags: batch-file, cmd, export, token, export-to-csv

I saw a nice script [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61961307/remotely-get-serial-number-and-model-from-list-in-batch-script) - this code get the Serial Number and Model from list of Remote Computers and export it to csv file.
The only problem is, that the export results have many separated lines instead of **ONE** line each computer.

I mean, i want to get this:

[image]

But i get that:

[image]

I also checked [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309295/get-computer-name-using-serial-number-of-server-remotely), but cant get it to work as described.

Here the Batch Code:

```
@echo off
del list.csv 2>nul
for /f %%i in (pclist.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%M in ('wmic /node:"%%i" csproduct get name /value') do for %%m in (%%M) do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%S in ('wmic /node:"%%i" bios get serialnumber /value') do for %%s in (%%S) do (
      >>list.csv echo %%i, %%s, %%m
    )
  )
)
type list.csv
pause
```

How do i make the results to export to one line (display SN and model) to each computer?

Comment: Please share the CSV files as text (properly [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)), not as Excel snapshots! What exactly can't you get work?

Comment: BTW, there was more than one answer in your first linked question, what was wrong with using the method from the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a go at this.

```
@echo off
break>list.csv
for /f "delims=" %%i in (pclist.txt) do call :method %%~i
type list.csv
goto :eof

:method
set "host_name=%~1"
for /f "tokens=2* delims==" %%N in ('wmic /node:"%~1" csproduct get name /value') do set "name=%%N"
for /f "tokens=2* delims==" %%S in ('wmic /node:"%~1" bios get serialnumber /value') do set "serial=%%S"
(echo %host_name%,%serial%,%name%)>>list.csv
```

We just get each of the values once, seeing as we do not incorporate `for` loops in `for` loops. Though we could have done this without setting variables, in this instance it makes it a little more readable.

Comment: Works like a charm! Do you have that also in PowerShell as well?

Comment: @StackBuck, If I post a PowerShell version, will I you accept it as your chosen solution? or, will Gerhard still get that? I don't want an answer, I want you to understand that if you have a new question, you post a new question. If you were to do that, of course, you'd need to also include a [mcve] of your failing code, as this site does not provide a code request service.

Comment: Here's my [PowerShell Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573413/remotely-get-serial-number-and-model-from-list-file-and-export-it-to-arranged-ex).