# Remotely get serial number and model from list file and export it to arranged excel in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, import, export-to-csv

I have Nice PowerShell code that Remotely gets the serial number and model (along with other Details) from list and export it to nice view in PowerShell.

However, i want to export it to an arranged csv file, so instead of this:

[image]

I'll have that:

[image]

Here's the **Original** code:

```
$ArrComputers =  "yakovcomputer"
#Specify the list of PC names in the line above. "." means local system

Clear-Host
foreach ($Computer in $ArrComputers) 
{
    $computerSystem = get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer $Computer
    $computerBIOS = get-wmiobject Win32_BIOS -Computer $Computer
    $computerOS = get-wmiobject Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $Computer
    $computerCPU = get-wmiobject Win32_Processor -Computer $Computer
    $computerHDD = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Computer -Filter drivetype=3
        write-host "System Information for: " $computerSystem.Name -BackgroundColor DarkCyan
        "-------------------------------------------------------"
        "Manufacturer: " + $computerSystem.Manufacturer
        "Model: " + $computerSystem.Model
        "Serial Number: " + $computerBIOS.SerialNumber
        "CPU: " + $computerCPU.Name
        "HDD Capacity: "  + "{0:N2}" -f ($computerHDD.Size/1GB) + "GB"
        "HDD Space: " + "{0:P2}" -f ($computerHDD.FreeSpace/$computerHDD.Size) + " Free (" + "{0:N2}" -f ($computerHDD.FreeSpace/1GB) + "GB)"
        "RAM: " + "{0:N2}" -f ($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB) + "GB"
        "Operating System: " + $computerOS.caption + ", Service Pack: " + $computerOS.ServicePackMajorVersion
        "User logged In: " + $computerSystem.UserName
        "Last Reboot: " + $computerOS.ConvertToDateTime($computerOS.LastBootUpTime)
        ""
        "-------------------------------------------------------"
}
```

So i try to add `Import-Csv C:list.txt | ForEach-Object` (that have the **yakovcomputer** name in it) at the start

(Undecided if to use `$computers = Get-Content c:\list.txt` instead),

And add `export-csv c:\temp\list.csv` command at the end.

So now it is look like that (**Edited code**):

```
Import-Csv C:list.csv | ForEach-Object
    {
        $computerSystem = get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer $Computer
        $computerBIOS = get-wmiobject Win32_BIOS -Computer $Computer
        $computerOS = get-wmiobject Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $Computer
        $computerCPU = get-wmiobject Win32_Processor -Computer $Computer
        $computerHDD = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Computer -Filter drivetype=3
    }
export-csv c:\temp\list.csv
```

But it keeps giving errors all the time.

I'm aware that I'm writing something (code) wrong here, but, what is the correct way to achieve that?

Comment: When piping to [Foreach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7), the current piped in object is `$_` or `$PSItem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `list.txt` is just a plain text file of computer names, with one name per line, `Get-Content` will be enough. You can access the current line (current item) with `$_` or `$PSItem`.

`Export-Csv` requires **objects**. So you would have to convert your data into objects. There are several ways to do it, most of them require creating a [HashTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-5.1). Here is my preferred version:

```bsh
Get-Content c:\list.txt | foreach
{
    $computerSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer $_
    $computerBIOS = Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS -Computer $_
    $computerOS = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $_
    $computerCPU = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -Computer $_
    $computerHDD = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $_ -Filter drivetype=3
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        "Manufacturer" = $computerSystem.Manufacturer
        "Model" = $computerSystem.Model
        "Serial Number" = $computerBIOS.SerialNumber
        "CPU" = $computerCPU.Name
        "HDD Capacity"  = ("{0:N2}" -f ($($computerHDD|measure Size -sum).Sum/1GB) + "GB")
        "HDD Space" = ("{0:P2}" -f ($($computerHDD|measure FreeSpace -sum).Sum/$($computerHDD|measure Size -sum).Sum) + " Free (" + "{0:N2}" -f ($($computerHDD|measure FreeSpace -sum).Sum/1GB) + "GB)")
        "RAM" = ("{0:N2}" -f ($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB) + "GB")
        "Operating System" = ($computerOS.caption + ", Service Pack: " + $computerOS.ServicePackMajorVersion)
        "User logged In" = $computerSystem.UserName
        "Last Reboot" = $computerOS.ConvertToDateTime($computerOS.LastBootUpTime)
    }
} | Export-Csv c:\temp\list.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note the `$($computerHDD|measure Size -sum).Sum` constructs, to add up the values for all HDDs if there are multiple.

Also, consider using [CIM instead of WMI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/should-i-use-cim-or-wmi-with-windows-powershell/) instead.

Comment: I dont get any data. Got the [following results](https://i.imgur.com/yEoYEyI.jpg). Got the same when using New-Object.

Comment: @StackBuck See my edit (using new-object instead). You probably have an older powershell version

Comment: I try to load it via ps1 file, but got that [Error](https://i.imgur.com/xuS9pcK.jpg). But again, he did create the list.csv file but inside you see what i add above.

Comment: @StackBuck My updated code should work. The other error you mentioned is about excution policies and doesn't really have anything to do with this question, but rather running ps1 scripts in general. If you need help with that, research the error or open a new question if you can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

in powershell script not working only HDD lines

Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
Model: HP Pro3500 Series
Serial Number: CZC3191456
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3220 CPU @ 3.30GHz
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'.
At line:18 char:9

- ```
      "HDD Capacity: "  + "{0:N2}" -f ($computerHDD.Size/1GB) + "GB ...
  ```
- ```
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Division:String) [], RuntimeException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'.
At line:19 char:9

- ```
      "HDD Space: " + "{0:P2}" -f ($computerHDD.FreeSpace/$computer ...
  ```
- ```
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Division:String) [], RuntimeException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

RAM: 7,89GB
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, Service Pack: 0

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31391042)